# How to change Alexa talking speed?

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit, ssml

How to change Alexa talking/playback speed to super fast or super slow? Is there a way to manipulate the sampling rate of Alexa audio output?

Comment: Have you tried [SSML](https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#prosody)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **prosody** tag of SSML to modify the speed, pitch and volume of response speech.

Ex:

```
<speak>
   <prosody rate="medium">I speak in medium pace</prosody>.
   <prosody rate="slow">I speak in slow pace</prosody>.
   <prosody rate="fast">I speak in fast pace</prosody>.
   <prosody rate="x-fast">I speak in very fast pace</prosody>.
   <prosody rate="x-slow">I speak in very slow pace</prosody>.
</speak>
```

You can also give the speed of speech in %

```
<prosody rate="50%">I speak in 50% slower pace</prosody>
```

Percentages greater than 100% increase the rate, percentages below 100% decrease the rate.

More information [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#prosody)

Comment: I'm new to this, correct me if I'm wrong. I created a lambda function and tried to replace the outputspeech 'type' to 'SSML' following doc examples, but not all the application index.js files have 'outputspeech'.